# How can convert bytea to base64 in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have now facing the problem in bytea to Base64, actually I have save the image in below query,

`user_profile_pic` is defind in `bytea` in table

```
Update user_profile_pic
Set user_profile_pic = (profilepic::bytea)
Where userid = userid;
```

after that I have select the below query,

```
case 1:  
SELECT user_profile_pic  
  FROM user_profile_pic;
```

its return exact same as I have updated, but after passing service its display a byte format

```
case 2:  
Select encode(user_profile_pic::bytea, 'base64')  
FROM user_profile_pic;
```

it returns totally different result.

I want to result case 1 along with service?

Comment: What is `profilepic`? What datatype/what format?

Comment: pass "profilepic" in base64 throe service

Comment: `profilepic::bytea` has no way of knowing that your input is base64. You probably want `decode(profilepic, 'base64')` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its working for me, not working query if write procedure/function, i write direct code behind

```
conn.Open();

                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT profile_pic FROM userlog WHERE cust_id = '" + CustID + "'", conn);
                Byte[] result = (Byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
                if(result.Length > 0)
                {
                    ProfilePicture = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
                    ErrorNumber = 0;
                    ErrorMessage = "Successful operation";
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorNumber = 1;
                }
                conn.Close();
```